# Url-aliases or redirect without language prefix

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases, redirection

How can I use url-aliases in additional languages without the language prefix?

From his old homebrew-CMS, my client has the following URLs:

- example.com/english-page => redirecting to example.com/en/node/1
- example.com/deutsche-seite => redirecting to example.com/de/node/1

I use Drupal 9.5.9, Redirect 8.x-1.8 and Pathauto 8.x-1.11. Default Language is German (de)

node 1 in German has url-alias '/deutsche-seite'
node 1 in its English Translation has url-alias '/english-page'

Opening the Site with the following URLs leads to different Results:

- example.com/en/english-page => OK, opens in english
- example.com/de/deutsche-seite => OK, opens in german
- example.com/deutsche-seite => OK. Redirects to /de/deutsche-seite which opens in german.
- example.com/english-page => Not OK, throws a 404.

How can I achieve that example.com/english-page redirects to example.com/en/english-page or renders the english translation of node 1?
I did not find any settings on pathauto or languages, and if I try to create an Redirect manually, the redirect-module does not allow me to enter a path without language prefix (https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/3208013)

Thanks a lot for any hint...
Kind regards, mullzk

Comment: When you say it won't let you add the DE specific redirect for /english-page. Do you mean its showing an error? Or just that its showing "/de" in the domain when entering the URL? As newer versions of redirect don't show the language selector and what you're trying should work fine

Comment: I am not sure I understand... I think I have the newest version of redirect (8.x-1.8) and there still is a language selector. 
The field 'Path' is prefixed with a language code (the one of current language or whatever set by the language selector. 
But my problem is in the 'To'-Field, where I should be able to point to the english-page, but it takes only the Node and automatically switches the language, and does not use /en/ if the url /english-page is called

Comment: In the language field you'd need to select DE, in the "from" field enter "english-page", in the "to" select node 1 (using the autocomplete which will be in german)

Comment: this does prevent a 404, but does not solve the problem. When calling example.com/english-page, it gets redirected to example.com/de/deutsche-seite. instead, it should be redirected to example.com/en/english-page

Comment: Did you check your Language settings? Does your English language settings have the "en" as the prefix? Usually the English as a default language is the only one that has en empty prefix.

Comment: My default language is German / de. But yes, all the languages are prefixed. Non-Prefixed paths are redirected to /de/[unprefixed], which is exactly my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve problem
1sy is patch for 9.x, 10.x branch. Dont working for me, but you can try
link: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2689459

Second is lang neutral aliases module. It works for me ok
https://www.drupal.org/project/language_neutral_aliases